# Body of response from web-server has value "<body><script language="javaScript">window.parent.document.cookie="Authorization=;path=/";

Tags: php, android, http, request

When I make GET request to web-server which is located in localhost by typing address in browser address field I get correct answer in json format. But when I make the same request from Android Studio I get response with status 200 (OK) but the value of body of this response is

```
<body><script language="javaScript">window.parent.document.cookie="Authorization=;path=/";
window.parent.location.href = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x";
</script></body></html>
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to connect to wrong ip-address

Answer (score 0):

What does your PHP file (I assume it's a php file) look like on the web-server?
The only thing it needs to output is the following:

```
<?PHP
$data = [];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Do not use html to output a json string for api requests.